# Act Together: how many times?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, summoner, eidolon

One question: I don't find the rule that you can use Act Together just once in a round. Technically I can use it three times and me (summoner) and my eidolon can make three one-action activities each one. Am I wrong?

Example: Action 1: eidolon strikes on Act Together => summoner strides [free] Action 2: eidolon strikes again on Act Together (-5 penalty) => summoner strikes (-10 penalty) [free] Action 3: eidolon move on Act Together => summoner uses a one-action cantrip [free]

Is it possible?

Example 2: Action 1: summoner casts a 2-actions spells on Act Together => eidolon strikes [free] Action 2: summoner moves on Act Together => eidolon strikes again (-5 penalty) [free]

If this is right, then basically Act Together options means that you have 3 (no use Act Together at all) up to 6 actions available for round (use three one-action activity, each one on Act Together), but you can't use them as normal. The acting is effectively together: the summoner and the eidolon are linked in simbiosis. In the case of 6 actions, 3 of them are of the summoner, the other 3 of the eidolon etc. Tell me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: What game is this about?

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking about Pathfinder 2nd edition, specifically (in which case the question should have the [pathfinder-2e] tag edited into it). Is that correct?

Comment: It could *also* be Pathfinder 1e, though I don't know of Act Together there

Comment: There is not, this is referencing 2e. https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/ has no reference to "Act Together"

Comment: Even further, the question references Multiple Attack Penalty (-5/-10), 3 Actions, activities, 1-action Cantrips, and 2-action spells. Virtually certain this is a question on Pathfinder 2e.

Answer (score 6):

### [Act Together](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=758) is Once per Round

> **Frequency** once per round
>
> ---
>
> You and your eidolon act as one. Either you or your eidolon takes an action or activity using the same number of actions as Act Together, and the other takes a single action. For example, if you spent 2 actions to Act Together, you could cast burning hands (2 actions) and your eidolon could Strike (1 action), or your eidolon could use its Breath Weapon (2 actions) and you could Stride (1 action).

Comment: Thank you! I'm Italiano and in the Italian translation there Is no mention of frequency.

Comment: @MarcoMazzotti Interesting, that might be worth reporting to whoever translated it.

Comment: Yes, I reported and now the translation Is complete